# netbeans not generating classes when build is issues, but the program runs when compiling

Tags: java, netbeans

So I have been using netbeans and successfully was able to do generate jar file in the dist folder ( using clean & build).

Now suddenly this does not work. It generates a jar file that does not run. Upon inspection, I found that the jar file does not have classes in it ( only folder structure). I also noticed that the build folder does not have classes.

However, when I run it by clicking the green arrow, it runs and the build folder has classes. When  I do Clean/build to generate the jar file in the dist folder, then the build folder resorts to empty classes and empty jar file.

Any idea? I restarted netbeans, did a refresh and all that but no luck

Please help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution for many people running into this issue. It is the missing eclipseLink Library